# Dynamically size nested UIStackView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistackview

I have the following structure:

[image]

I have this StackView in my prototype TableView cell. Inside this `StackView` there are two views. The first one is a normal 'UIView' whose content is known before runtime. The second is another `StackView` which I will fill with multiple `UIViews` on runtime.

The inner `StackView` is set hidden from the beginning and will only be shown, when the cell is clicked. Now my Problem is, that I can't manage to get the cell to the right size (height) after dynamically adding these `UIViews` to the `StackView`.

I call `sizeToFit()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` for the inner `StackView` and every `UIView` inside when updating the cell.

This is my Code which fills the inner `UIStackView` (it is in java, because I am using multi-os-engine but it is quite similar to swift/objective-c).

```
UIView parent = cell.orderDetailsView();
parent.subviews().makeObjectsPerformSelector(new SEL("removeFromSuperview"));

for (int i = 0; i < order.getOrderItems().size(); i++) {
    UserOrderItem item = order.getOrderItems().get(i);

    NSArray nibContents = nibBundle().loadNibNamedOwnerOptions("OrderListItem", this, null);
    UIView itemView = ((UIView) nibContents.lastObject()).subviews().get(0);
    parent.addSubview(itemView);

    // shortened code: here I set some uilabel content inside of the itemView

    if( i == 0) {
        NSLayoutConstraint c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(itemView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 5);
        parent.addConstraint(c1);
    }
    if (i == order.getOrderItems().size()-1) {
        // add last item
        NSArray nibContents2 = nibBundle().loadNibNamedOwnerOptions("OrderListTotalPrice", this, null);
        UIView totalPriceView = ((UIView) nibContents2.lastObject()).subviews().get(0);
        parent.addSubview(totalPriceView);
        ((UILabel) totalPriceView.subviews().get(0)).setText(DisplayUtils.getEuroString(order.getOrderFee()));
        ((UILabel) totalPriceView.subviews().get(1)).setText(DisplayUtils.getEuroString(order.getTotalPrice()));

        NSLayoutConstraint c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(totalPriceView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, -5);
        parent.addConstraint(c1);

        NSLayoutConstraint c2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(totalPriceView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 5);
        parent.addConstraint(c2);
        NSLayoutConstraint c3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(totalPriceView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, -5);
        parent.addConstraint(c3);
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint c2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(itemView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 5);
    parent.addConstraint(c2);

    NSLayoutConstraint c3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(itemView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, parent, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, -5);
    parent.addConstraint(c3);

    itemView.layoutIfNeeded();
    itemView.setNeedsDisplay();
}
// calling sizetofit and layoutifneeded for every subview here
```

PS: My outer StackView is set to `Fill equally` which I think is causing the problem, but when setting it to proportional or just fill the inner `StackView` gets just prompted above the first element (orderview).

The inner StackView is set to `fill proportionally`.

Comment: A little tough to say because it's not clear what all you're doing with your constraints, but... First, both stack views should be set to `Fill`. Second, you shouldn't need either `itemView.layoutIfNeeded();` or `itemView.setNeedsDisplay();`. Third, when you want to show or hide the nested stack view, are you calling `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake: I needed to use `.addArrangedSubview()` instead of `.addSubview()`.

This fixed the whole problem.